# How to split a string based on a regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hi & thanks for looking!

In C#, I have a string coming into a method that is delimited by a pattern like this:

`some text ;#1;# some more text ;#2;# even more text`

I would like to split the spring based on these patterns (`;#1;#`).

Is it possible to split based on multiple characters? If so, how would I handle for the number in the middle of the delimiter?

**Note:** In some cases, there may be a double or even tripple digit in the delimiter.  For example, `;#10;#` or `;#123;#`.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx), or are you asking what Regex would do this?  If you want a regex, `;#\d+;#` should do it (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I split a string using regex to return a list of values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93983/how-can-i-split-a-string-using-regex-to-return-a-list-of-values)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93983/how-can-i-split-a-string-using-regex-to-return-a-list-of-values , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526464/i-need-to-split-a-string-based-on-a-complex-delimiter , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93983/how-can-i-split-a-string-using-regex-to-return-a-list-of-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Split(string s, string pattern)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) method. The pattern you need is `";#[0-9]+;#"`

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(
    "some text ;#1;# some more text ;#2;# even more text"
,   ";#[0-9]+;#"
);
```

Comment: Nailed it!  Thanks for the help, links and example.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a wrong regex, but this is how you do it.

```
string input = "some text ;#1;# some more text ;#2;# even more text";
string pattern = ";#[0-9]+;#";            // Split by pattern
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx

Comment: You would probably want to constrain the pattern a little more than just `*`.  And you probably don't need the captures if you won't use them.